# JOptionPane doesn't disappear until next JOptionPane appears

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, invokelater

I have a process that shows confirm messages from JOptionPane. This process is called from SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable) that is inside an Actionlistener for a JMenuItem. The code for the runnable is this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        MyClass c=new MyClass(file)
                        try {
                            c.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            this.finalize();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

In MyClass there's this method:

```
private boolean userInput(){
    String message="yes or no?";
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Do this for all.");
    Object[] params={message,checkbox};
    int n=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,params,"message",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    boolean answer=(n==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)?true:false;
    if(checkbox.isSelected()){
        nextQ=false;
        nextA=answer;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

which is called many times. When a JOptionPane message is displayed, I click its button(yes/no), but the message won't disappear until the next message is displayed. What might be the problem? Does this has to do with the method invokeLater ?

Comment: try to do reavlidate(); repaint()

Comment: no idea without your SSCCE / MCVE, short runnable, compilable, this isn't somehow special task,

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Still waiting for an MCVE and why are you calling `start` and `finalize` inside the `Runnable`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the way to solve this. I had to create a new Thread inside the SwingUrtilities.invokeLater method. This is the new code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        MyClass c=new MyClass(file)
                        public void run(){
                          c.start(); 
                        }
                     }); 
                     t.start();      
                }
            });
```